# How to Insert <link/> tag into <head> in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to insert html into the head of my WordPress site, the plan is to insert a link tag to preload my main css file so that when it is loaded using `wp_enqueue_style` it is already preloaded. But I'm not entirely sure how to do this, I've seen a few similar issues and have tried a few approaches with no luck, currently I am trying:

```
function preload_styles() {
  $href = 'styles/main.css';
  echo `<link rel='preload' as='style' id='main-css' href='$href' type='text/css'/>`;
}

add_action( 'wp_head','preload_styles', 10);
```

But it seems to be doing nothing... Nothing is being inserted into the head. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are messing with a single quote and double quote. Try the below code.

```
function preload_styles() {
    $href = 'styles/main.css';
    echo '<link rel="preload" as="style" id="main-css" href="'.$href.'" type="text/css/">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head','preload_styles', 10);
```

Tested and works

[image]